# Installing ruby gems ruby-libvirt, vagrant-libvirt, fog-libvirt… failure missing « libvirt » library

Tags: ruby, linux, vagrant, libvirt

When trying to install ruby gems to enable libvirt management for vagrant, the installation fails with a undocumented message « it depends on a library which is not currently installed : libvirt ».

Libvirt is working, I am able to compile manually « vagrant-libvirt », and even starting and configuring qemu VMs using virsh.

The host is a VMWare one, but the nested virtualization is enabled.
The Virtualization « VT-x » is visible thru lscpu and « vmx / svm » capabilities are presents in /proc/cpuinfo.

```
Vagrant failed to install the requested plugin because it depends
on a library which is not currently installed on this system. The
following library is required by the 'vagrant-libvirt' plugin:

  libvirt

Please install the library and then run the command again.
```

I have installed all packages / gems https://computingforgeeks.com/use-vagrant-with-libvirt-kvm-on-centos/ and cannot figure how ruby is trying to talk to libvirt, with which library that may be missing.

Tried both with RHEL, Centos8 (alma), Debian sid.

Comment: Do you have `libvirt-dev` installed? I think Ruby may be trying to compile a gem which depends on `libvirt-dev`.

Comment: Yes I did :) the problem seems more obvious.

Comment: You can try to set the env `VAGRANT_LOG`  to `debug`, and then paste the output here. Perhaps there are some clues in there.

Comment: This was the right path. The solution is the Hashicorp vagrants needs to known where he stores his own libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to https://GitHub.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/issues/1104 , the problem was really a library path not defined.

The true solution for this problem with Hashicorp released vagrant packages is to force the libraries to vagrant:

```
CONFIGURE_ARGS='with-ldflags=-L/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib with-libvirt-include=/usr/include/libvirt with-libvirt-lib=/usr/lib64' GEM_HOME=~/.vagrant.d/gems GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems PATH=/opt/vagrant/embedded/bin:$PATH vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [installation guide](https://vagrant-libvirt.github.io/vagrant-libvirt/installation.html) in the documentation page for vagrant-libvirt, you should check that out first, in case if you haven't already.

Package maintainers sometimes choose to split libraries into base and developer packages. Usually, base package should fulfill the requirements, but in some cases, you might also need the developer packages. In Debian-based distros, you can find `*-dev`, and in Fedora-based distros, you can find `*-devel` packages.

On a side note, if you're having a hard time searching for an alternative software package manager, you should make use of this webpage - [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/).

Comment: Yes I did. In fact, the strange thing with the way the gems are handled is that I cannot figure how it is handling the dependency chain, neither the real error it encounters. It may be a missing package issue, but in that case, the error is all but explicit :)